# Special characters in QUrl will be transformed to punycode

Tags: qt, special-characters, punycode, qurl

I'm having a textfield where the user can add an URL with I'm having a textfield where the user can add an URL with `QUrl::fromUserInput()` and it then will be put into a list. 
If I use special characters in the URL like `"http://blöd.de/"` it will be shown as `"http://blöd.de/"` but if I only type in `"ö"` it will get converted to the punycode `"http://xn--nda/"`.

I tried every `QUrl::FormattingOptions` and every `QUrl::ParsingMode`

```
qDebug() << QUrl::fromUserInput("blöd.de"); // results in: http://blöd.de
qDebug() << QUrl::fromUserInput("ö");       // results in: http://xn--nda
```

Does somebody have an idea how I can convert this punycode back to the special character? And why is it only not converted when I have a top level domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason some urls are shown with Unicode characters and others with punnycode is to prevent homograph attacks.

One way to decide how to behave for a specific url is by the mean of a TLD whitelist.
In Qt you can see and edit the whitelist using `QUrl::idnWhitelist()` and `QUrl::setIdnWhitelist(const QStringList &list)`.

In your example `.de` is in the whitelist, but `.ö` is not. That is why you can see a difference in behaviour.